# bfgminer 'Rejected' problem

Tags: bfgminer

I'm running bfgminer with block erupters, and all is working fine 90% of the time. However, if my internet connection drops briefly, then I get nothing but Rejected shares from that point onwards. This never rectifies itself unless I restart bfgminer. This probably happens once every few days which is a little frustrating.

Does anyone have any idea why is happens?  And what I can do about it?

Thanks

[image: Rejected Shares]?

Comment: Report a bug to the bfgminer developers?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, and also looking for a solution. I tried [CGWatcher](http://manotechnology.blogspot.com.br/p/cgwatcher.html) but it was more buggy than the bfgminer itself from my experience (maybe it was just me, that couldn't configure it correctly?). If all else fails, I'll try to do something using the API (ex.: restart miner after N rejects) - once I have enough time for that... :(

Comment: Are you using the current version?

Answer (score 1):

Bugs can be reported at https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/

Please run with --log-file debug.log --debuglog -P and upload the entire file to Dropbox (or equivalent); if you have sensitive information (passwords?), be sure they are not in the log file before publishing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different miner, for example cgminer or minerd.